# In this situation, based on order of operations, would cross product happen first or dot product?

Tags: matrices, cross-product

I got from wikipedia that the dot product is also referred to as the "scalar product" and that the cross product is also referred to as the "vector product". Can anyone confirm my inference on the order of operations based off the previous statement?

Say I have three vectors, A, B, and C.

If I perform this operation

D = A * B X C.

I know in basic arithmetic, there is PEMDAS, where if you had something like d = 4 + 3 * 2, the 3 * 2 operation would be completed first. Is there also similar for vector operations. Based my inference, I assume here that the cross product gets calculated first, then the dot product. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: The only way $A\cdot B\times C$ can make sense is if you read it as $A\cdot (B\times C)$, because if you read it as $(A\cdot B)\times C$, then you're computing the cross product of the scalar $A\cdot B$ with the vector $C$, which doesn't make sense. I would however say that $A\cdot B\times C$ is simply something devoided of meaning and shouldn't be written.

Comment: I disagree that it's without meaning, but I would say it's bad form.

Comment: @jvriesem if it is not without meaning, then what is it's meaning?

Comment: @Aatmaj A*BxC should probably be interpreted as A*(BxC). Also, if somebody wrote it, they must have meant something by it, even if that intended meaning isn’t clear to the reader. Good form would be to write an expression in a manner that is unambiguous and conventional.

Comment: thanks @jvriesem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cross product would have to occur first. If not, then you can not use the operation because after you do the dot product, you would have a scalar and a vector, not two vectors. You are correct in thinking so!

Comment: And the operation wouldn't work because cross product can only occur between two vectors in R3?

Comment: @committedandroider Yes. Git Gud has a good explanation of it as well.